# Solving a system of two equations of third degree

Tags: equation-solving, system

I am trying to solve the following system of two equations for x and y. The solutions for x and y have to be positive and the parameters s and c are positive (to have a coherent interpretation of my problem). Could anyone please help me?

```
eq1 := (2 + 12*s)/(9*x^2) + (4*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*x^2*y) - (4*Sqrt[2*s])/( 9*x^3) - k

eq2 := (1 + 3*Sqrt[2*s] - 6*s)/(9*y^2) + (2*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*y^2*x) - (2*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*y^3) - k

Solve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, y}, Positive]
```

Comment: `Positive` is not a legitimate domain as the 3rd argument to `Solve. What, exactly, is intended to be positive -- just the desired values of `x` and `y`? If so, how do you expect *Mathematica* to do that when you don't say anything about the values of `k`? (Or by 'c` do you actually mean `k`?)

Comment: If you multiply each equation by the greatest common denominator of its terms, you'll see that in fact you have a pair of *fourth* degree equations, not third degree.

Comment: Let's try an example: `s = 4; k = 1;`. Then `Reduce[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]` yields a set of solutions involving `Root` expressions for *eight* degree polynomials!

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to enforce positivity of solutions without specifying actual values for the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of finding the general solution of your equations:

Define the expressions

```
expr1 = (2 + 12*s)/(9*x^2) + (4*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*x^2*y) - (4*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*x^3) - k;
expr2 = (1 + 3*Sqrt[2*s] - 6*s)/(9*y^2) + (2*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*y^2*x) - (2*Sqrt[2*s])/(9*y^3) - k;
```

Solve for `y` in terms of `x`.

```
ysol = Solve[expr1 == 0, y]

(* {{y -> (4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] x)/(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] - 2 x - 12 s x + 9 k x^3)}} *)
```

Solve for `x`.

```
xsol = Solve[expr2 == 0 /. ysol, x]

(* <large Root expressions> *)
```

Verify the solutions.

```
{expr1, expr2} /. ysol /. xsol // FullSimplify

(* {{{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}, {{0, 0}}} *)
```

Comment: But this does still not give any closed-form explicit solution, as the solution still involves `Root` objects.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "closed-form explicit"! I sense that you actually want a solution expressed in terms of "elementary" functions, but in this case you are out of luck because the polynomial degree is too high.

Comment: I suspect that the O.P. did expect to obtain such a "closed-form explicit". While I'm well aware of Abel's Theorem prohibiting a "general formula" for higher-degree polynomial equations, particular higher-order polynomial equations can be solved, and it *might* have been the case that the particular system about which the O.P. asked would lead to such.

Comment: Many thanks for your insights. The variables (x and y) and parameters (s and c) have to be positive. I think will not be able to get a general solution for this system.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.